# R - change X axis values to categories

Tags: r

I am trying to draw a scatter dot plot for this data

```
head(data)
  Subject Length  Verdict
1     2   4575  Partial
2     2   5060  Partial
3     2   8978 5'DEFECT
4     2   7224  Partial
5     2   7224  Partial
6     7   8978 5'DEFECT
```

I get a scatter dot plot as such:

[image: Scatter dot plot]

I have patients 1,2,6,7,10 for example. R is taking the names of my subjects and using them as an x-value. I want to change that so the data points appear above each patient (not treated as a value, but rather as a category).

Appreciate your help!

Here's the code I wrote to get this scatter dot plot:

```
ggplot(final,
       aes(x=Subject,y=Length,colour=Verdict,shape=Verdict), group=Subject) +
  geom_point(position=position_jitter(width=0.1,height=0)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(5,0,1,4,6)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue","red","green","black","violet")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(2000,4000,6000,8000,10000)) +
  labs(y="Amplicon Size in bps")
```

Comment: Try replacing `x=Subject` with `x=as.factor(Subject)` or `x=as.character(Subject)`.

Comment: Oh that is beautiful Mike! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the sample data you posted (the 6 observations), you can do this easily with `as.factor` or `as.character`. I recommend converting your `Subject` variable to a character first (since it sounds like you don't want it to be treated as numeric anyway).

This should work:

```
data$Subject <- as.character(data$Subject)

ggplot(data,
       aes(x=Subject,y=Length,colour=Verdict,shape=Verdict), group=Subject) +
  geom_point(position=position_jitter(width=0.1,height=0)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(5,0,1,4,6)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue","red","green","black","violet")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(2000,4000,6000,8000,10000)) +
  labs(y="Amplicon Size in bps")
```

[image]

**Data:**

```
data <- structure(list(Subject = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 7L), Length = 
                  c(4575L, 5060L, 8978L, 7224L, 7224L, 8978L), Verdict = c("Partial", "Partial", 
                  "5'DEFECT", "Partial", "Partial", "5'DEFECT")), .Names = c("Subject", 
                  "Length", "Verdict"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `as.factor(data$Subject)` and `scale_x_discrete("Subject")`. Here a dummy example:

```
data <- read.table(textConnection('i    Subject Length  Verdict
1   2   4575    Partial
2   2   5060    Partial
3   2   8978    5DEFECT
4   2   7224    Partial
5   2   7224    Partial
6   7   8978    5DEFECT'), header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data$Subject <- as.factor(data$Subject)
p = ggplot(data) + geom_point(aes(x=Subject,y=Length, colour=Verdict))+ scale_shape_manual(values= c(5,0,1,4,6))
p = p + scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue","red","green","black","violet"))
p = p+ scale_x_discrete("Subject")
p = p + scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(2000,4000,6000,8000,10000))+labs(y="Amplicon Size in bps")
p
```